# Incrementar a partir del ultimo valor obtenido

Tags: javascript

Esta función a partir del evento `onclick` empieza desde cero incrementándose de 16 en 16 y a su vez la cookie obtiene ese valor. Pero si actualizo la pagina me muestra el valor obtenido pero, si hago click comienza desde 16 y necesito que lo haga a partir del ultimo valor obtenido, por ejemplo si quedo en 16 y hago click no muestra 32 sino empieza desde 16, esto solo lo hace si se actualiza la pagina. De lo contrario el incremento lo hace bien.

```
<script>
 var widthValue = 0;
 var elem = document.getElementById("progress");
 var widthAnim = widthValue;

function incremento() { 
        var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
        var widthIncrement = 16; /*<----*/
        widthValue = widthAnim + widthIncrement;
     var expire = new Date( 2029, 25, 07, 12, 01 );
        var cookieName = "pv";
        var cookiePercentage = widthValue;
        document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(cookieName) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cookiePercentage) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
       
        function frame() {       
            if (widthAnim >= widthValue || widthValue > 100) {
              clearInterval(id);
            } else {            
                widthAnim++;
                elem.style.width = widthAnim + "%";
                elem.innerHTML =  widthAnim * 1 + "% Completado";      
              }                                               
        }      
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar el valor de la cookie:

```
function cookieValue(cookieName, defaultValue){

let valorCookie = 

document.cookie // recuperar las cookies
       .split(`${cookieName}=`)[1] // hacer split por nombreCookie= y tomar la posición 1
       ?.split(';')[0] // hacer split por ; y tomar la posición 0
       ?? encodeURIComponent(defaultValue); // si lo anterior es undefined retornar el valor por defecto
       
       return decodeURIComponent(valorCookie) * 1; // convertir a entero

}
```

Uso:

```
var widthIncrement = cookieValue(nombreCookie,16);
```